# Windows media player stutters at the beginning and end of each song when streamed from a network library

Tags: windows-7, music, windows-media-player, media

Windows media player (on Win7, 64bit) shows "Other Libraries" - so I can play music from my desktop machine on my laptop.  This is great, except the music stutters for maybe the first 15 seconds and last 15 second of each song.  I would assume a network problem, but oddly if I browse to the network library with Windows Explorer instead, and launch media player by double clicking an mp3 file, it plays fine!  The stuttering only happens when you browse to the network library through Media Player.

Not a big deal, but I want to know why this happens!

Comment: does it happen with video? noticeable slowdown or stuttering while playing video from the network library?

Comment: Hadn't tried it before, but yes, video is the same.

Comment: I would just try a different media player and see if they act the same. VLC or Media Player Classic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_player_software If it happens the same way with one of those apps then it would be a hardware problem and not software.